# updated php from 7.4 to 8.2 and woocommerce-autoship-authorize-net-payments doesnt work now

Tags: php, wordpress, authorize.net, woocommerce-subscriptions

when i updated the php from 7.4 to 8.2 i tried to access my site and do a checkout but it failed showing the error mentioned below.

I am using woocommerce-autoship-authorize-net-payments plugin for checkouts.

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Type" in property net\authorize\util\SensitiveDataConfigType::$sensitiveTags was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

i tried to intorduce use in file but it desnt work out.

Comment: The developer will need to update the code to be compatible with PHP8.2. There's nothing you can do here.